# generic call of class in c#

Tags: c#

```
SlovenianSearchQueryManager.ApplySloveniaQueries(rawQuery, page, pageSize, orderBy, out count);
```

is it possible to get SlovenianSearchQueryManager class by concatinating HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] and "SearchQueryManager";

HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] is Slovenian so together is SlovenianSearchQueryManager

next time

HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] is German so together is 
GermanSearchQueryManager

i try to make this generic instead of making

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] == "Slovenian)
{ 
SlovenianSearchQueryManager.ApplySloveniaQueries(rawQuery, page, pageSize, orderBy, out count);
} 
else ...
```

i want to make something like

```
(HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] + "SearchQueryManager").ApplySloveniaQueries(...
```

is this even possible to make something like this and the type SlovenianSearchQueryManager for example exists, it's in a different class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) and [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
var queryManagerType = Type.GetType(HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] + "SearchQueryManager");
var queryManager = Activator.CreateInstance(queryManagerType);
```

[Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) returns an object. You might want to define an interface that you query managers will need to implement.

```
public interface ISearchQueryManager {
    void ApplyQueries(/* add parameters here */);
}
```

Then you can cast the object returned by CreateInstance to the interface:

```
var queryManagerType = Type.GetType(HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"] + "SearchQueryManager");
var queryManager = (ISearchQueryManager)Activator.CreateInstance(queryManagerType);
queryManager.ApplyQueries(rawQuery, page, pageSize, orderBy, out count);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make an `ISearchQueryManager` interface with implementations for each language, then use a `Dictionary<string, ISearchQueryManager>` to get the implementation for the desired language.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making two changes.

First, make all of your "SearchQueryManager" instances derive from a common interface (or base class), such as `ISearchQueryManager`.

Second, make a `Dictionary<string, ISearchQueryManager>`, and use it to lookup the appropriate one based on your type.

You could then do:

```
 ISearchQueryManager manager;
 if (!managers.TryGetValue(HttpContext.Current.Session["lang_name"], out manager))
 {
     // Unknown language - handle this!
 }    
 else
 {
       manager.ApplyQuery(...);
 }
```

Comment: thx for answer. do you have any link how to make this? i search but i can not find any example.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the factory pattern. Define an interface, like IQueries with the queries methods you need. Then define a factory class that takes your language and returns an IQueries. For slovenia, return your SlovenienSearchQueryManager. Etc for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to work around creating a factory pattern, which would, IMO, be the correct way to solve this problem.

http://aspalliance.com/809

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate using a factory class to create your query managers.

Pseudo-code:

```
var factory= new QueryManagerFactory();
var queryManager = factory.Create("Slovenian");
```

In your factory create method return the type of query manager you want based upon the input.